# What weaknesses are worth investigating in this non-linear matrix cipher?

Tags: encryption, finite-field, matrix-multiplication, hill-cipher

I have an interesting cipher based on matrix products that I've not seen before.

Given plaintext bytes $p\in[0,255]$, pad to a perfect square length and write into the entries of an $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{P}$.

Given a key $k$, apply some key derivation function $f$ to it to produce another $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{K}=f(k)\in[0,255]^{n\times n}$. We assume $f$ is ideal in some sense, so not considering $f$ itself as an attack vector here.

Assume $f$ is designed such that $\mathrm{gcd}(\det(\mathbf{K}), 256) = 1$.

To encrypt, we do $\mathbf{C} = \mathcal{E}(p) = \mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{P} \mathbf{K} \mod 256$.

To decrypt a given ciphertext $\mathbf{C}$ and knowing $k$ and thus $\mathbf{K}$ we just do this (all modulo 256):

$$
\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{K}^{-\top}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{K}^{-1}
$$

The $\mathrm{gcd}$ condition mentioned earlier should ensure that an inverse exists. The problem appears to be much harder than the linear Hill cipher because it is quadratic in entries of $\mathbf{K}$. A single incorrect entry in a *close* guess of $\mathbf{K}$ produces a seemingly random output, so the problem has no easy *gradient* to follow for some kind of greedy search or hill-climb.

I am only aware of a known plaintext attack where if $\mathbf{P}$ happens to be a positive definite matrix, then we can write $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{Y}^\top\mathbf{Y}$ and potentially do Cholesky decomposition or find a lattice isomorphism between $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{C}$. This particular integer matrix equation is also documented little online. From a cryptography standpoint, what other methods might make an attack more feasible than brute force?

---

An obvious problem with the above is when $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{0}$ then $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{0}$, and more generally it leaks information about zero entries in the plaintext. To mitigate this we could also derive an extra matrix $g(k)=\mathbf{A}$ from the key, and do $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{P} \mathbf{K} + \mathbf{A}$. For decryption we'd need to subtract this matrix from the ciphertext matrix first, then proceed as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, with this cipher, we have:

$$\mathcal{E}(p) + \mathcal{E}(q) = \mathcal{E}(p+q)$$

(and the addition operation is adding the matrix elements modulo 256)

That is, it is linear; the standard linear attacks work just fine.  A sufficient number of known plaintexts would be sufficient to allow you to decrypt anything.

Adding in the constant $A$ makes the cipher affine rather than linear; that just means we need a single extra known plaintext...

Comment: I see... 
$\mathbf{C}_1 + \mathbf{C}_2 = \mathbf{K}^\top\mathbf{P}_1\mathbf{K} + \mathbf{K}^\top\mathbf{P}_2\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{K}^\top(\mathbf{P}_1 + \mathbf{P}_2)\mathbf{K}$ so enough pairs of $\mathbf{P}_i,\mathbf{C}_i$ should determine $\mathbf{K}$. Doesn't the number of pairs grow as $n^2$ though, or is there a lower complexity?

Comment: @filnty Being linear is enough to mean the cipher cannot be $\mathsf{IND}-\mathsf{CPA}$ secure, the lowest acceptable notion of security for a cipher. This is to say what poncho has demonstrated is generally enough to be seen as a full attack already (though you are correct that given enough samples, key recovery should be possible as well)

Answer (score 2):

As poncho mentioned, your cipher is linear. You seemed initially to think that it was quadratic. This is just an answer to say that it is well-known that your equation can be rewritten to be of the form $P = A_K B_P$, where $A, B$ are matrices that depend on $K$ and $P$. This is done via the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations).
In particular, one can rewrite it as

$$\mathcal{E}(p) = \mathbf{K}^{-T}\mathbf{P}\mathbf{K} = (\mathbf{K}^{-T}\otimes \mathbf{K})\mathsf{vec}(\mathbf{P})$$

Here, we are required to reshape the matrix $\mathbf{P}$ to get the math to work out. Read the wikipedia page if you're interested.

In general your cipher construction is somewhat close to something that actually works.
In LWE-based cryptography, one can define a cipher

$$\mathsf{Enc}_{\vec s}(\vec m) = (\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{A}\vec s + \vec e + (q/2)\vec m)\bmod q$$

Here, the secret $\vec s\gets \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}^n$, $\vec e\gets\{-B, -B+1,\dots, B\}^n$, and $\mathbf{A}\gets \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$.
Standard choices of parameters are $n\approx 700$, $B\approx 10$, and $q\approx 3000$.
I haven't verified all the details for these ballpark parameters, but under well-accepted hardness assumptions the above will be correct and secure. It is also closely-related to the new (public key) replacement for Elliptic Curve cryptography that has just been standardized.

Comment: +1 Useful info. There's a mistake, it should be $\mathbf{K}^\top\mathbf{P}\mathbf{K}$ and $(\mathbf{K}^\top \otimes \mathbf{K}^\top) \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{P})$ if $\mathrm{vec}$ is the row-wise instead of the usual columnwise vec.